# Syntax for Passing Args to a Pandas Dataframe apply function

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, apply

My problem is here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply.

If you have

```
def subtract_custom_value(x, custom_value):
    return x-custom_value
```

then

```
series.apply(subtract_custom_value, args=(5,))
```

works, but not

```
series.apply(subtract_custom_value, args=(,5))
```

neither

```
series.apply(subtract_custom_value, args=(5))
```

I don't understand why they chose this syntax since in the order of "substract_custom_values" args, 5 is actually matching "custom_value", not x, which is "Series" supplied through "apply" function.

I thus wonder both why they chose to change the order so that the custom_value is first in args, and why the need of the comma at the end (not adding it breaks the syntax).

Thanks by advance

Comment: It's because the param arg must be a sequence and so you're passing a tuple and the first param to your func are the `Series` values so it looks weird, if you passed `args=([5])` then this would work as you're passing a sequence of a single element, this is why the other 2 attempts fails as `5` is not a sequence and `(,5)` doesn't match your params as you have 2 args but the first arg is already the `Series` values, if your func accepted 3 args then it would not raise an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They didn't choose anything like that. As stated in the docs you linked, `args` is expected to be a tuple. Use a tuple (or another kind of iterable) and it might work, provided the number and type of its elements are suitable. Use something that is not a iterable and it won't work. Use invalid python syntax and you'll get a syntax error. Python business as usual.

Now about your examples:

- `(5,)` is a tuple with one element.
- `(,5)` is not valid python syntax, there's nothing pandas can do about it.
- `(5)` evaluates to a number, not a tuple.

Comment: I know it had to be a  tuple. Actually, docs say "Tuple/Positional arguments to pass to function in addition to the value". So I tried something that was not a tuple, for observing apply's behavior. It was not evident that position in the tuple had not to mirror the one in method description once x taken into account. I was thinking it would more like some constructor in other langages (I come from java, sorry). Also, I am not used to such cases, so I was not aware syntax on 2nd case would be wrong. @EdChum seemed to say that (,5) could have been valid with 3 arguments. Thanks

Comment: Also, the formulation of my question was not meant to disrespect Pandas' team. I really believed they made a coding choice, and as everything in the libraries is very formal and logically chosen, this was confusing for me.

Comment: I did not read your question as disrespectful, sorry if I sounded like that. I jus wanted to clarify that syntax is part of the language definition and library authors do not have a say on it. I guess I did not make my point clear enough.

Comment: It was not as much meant to explain it to you that to those people that could have downvoted the question because my tone was not clear. I am glad that you helped me, actually. As I know a lot of bits of many langages (I never was taught formally, so I grab/learn what is useful when I need it, by lack of time and need of powerful tools) but still have a lot of room to get proficient on my own, that leads sometimes to such interrogations.